# How to createEvent based on form submit?

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar

A question I've seen a few times on the major coding support fora, how to add an event to a calendar based on a form submit. Nevertheless, I'm struggling.

| Timestamp form | Date | name | startTime | endTime | descr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25/05/2021 13:05:05 | =to_date(A2) | Meeting | 15:05:00 | 15:42:00 | garden |

The event would always take place on the date of the form submit. Nothing seems to come of the following code.

```
var spreadsheet   = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Form1");
var data          = spreadsheet.getRange("A2:F").getValues();

function toCal() {
    let [,  date, name, startTime, endTime, descr] = data;
    var calen = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("examplecal@group.calendar.google.com");
    calen.createEvent(name, 
    new Date(date + startTime), 
    new Date(date + endTime),
    {location: "Brandenburger Tor", description: descr});
  }
}
```

The event just needs to be based on the last submission, so I can put it on a "on form submit" trigger.

I think the trouble comes from the date time. However if I just put in `new Date("25/05/2021 15:05:00")` instead of a the current thing, nothing appears in my calendar as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are your values for `date` and `startTime`? Where are you getting them?

Comment: From a Sheet, as shown in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format B2 to 2021-05-25
[image]

and try:

```
function toCal() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Form1");
  var data = spreadsheet.getRange("A2:F2").getDisplayValues();
  start = new Date(data[0][1] + " " + data[0][3]);
  end = new Date(data[0][1] + " " + data[0][4]);
  var calen = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("examplecal@group.calendar.google.com");
  calen.createEvent(data[0][2], start, end,
    {location: "Brandenburger Tor", description: data[0][5]});
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This makes events based on the data in the second line, what if I wanted an event from the third line?

Comment: `var data = spreadsheet.getRange("A3:F3").getDisplayValues();`

Comment: Yes, thank you. How would I automate it going through my sheet and making an event based on the last line?
For instance, changing `var data = spreadsheet.getRange("A2:F2").getDisplayValues();` to `var data = spreadsheet.getRange(lastRow,2,lastRow,5).getDisplayValues();` (and adding `var lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow();`), does not work.

Comment: Maybe it will be more useful for other users of the Stackoverflow site if you ask this question in a new post?